# Rebuild recursive directive tree

Tags: angularjs, binary-tree, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a problem with with a recursive binary tree, which is build in a single directive.

I would like to change node and rebuild the subtree.

Here I use:

```
scope.$watch('node', function(newValue, oldValue) {
// rerun link
// to clean I use element.children().remove()
}
```

The problem is that at the leaf nodes I have got another directive, which should display a list with the Angular directive `ng-repeat`.

If the tree is changed;
I get an errror: there are item elements of `ng-repeat` missing parent directive
Could it be that `element.children().remove()` has some problems with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: please create a demo that replicates problem. If you use `ng-repeat` I don't know why you would need `remove()`

Comment: Pretty difficult, but I will try.

Comment: usually not that hard if you use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The problem had nothing to do with `ng-repeat`.

If somebody try something similiar:
Pay attention to the scopes of angular and clean it with.
`$scope.$destroy()`

Despite thanks for your comment.